# How to populate Forum Galleries from the posted URLs in forum database

Tags: images

I run a photography website in vBulletin and want to use the posted images, (hosted elsewhere on Smugmug, Flickr and other servers), to populate galleries for each registered forum member.

Is there a routine or APP that can search for and find, (and upload as images) all the posted external image links and populate an image gallery database and then update the image link to now point to the image stored in our new database?

If not do you know anyone who can write that routine for me?

I am currently using vBulletin 3.8 and migrating to Xenofo 2

Thanks,

Asher

Comment: Welcome aboard, Asher. You ask "`Is there a routine or APP that can search for and find ...`" F.Y.I if you are looking for a routine within vBulletin  then this is the place to ask. If you want an app, then please ask us at [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Good luck :-)

Comment: Maug, your response is so appreciated! Do you know of such a routine within vB? Unfortunately our wonderful IT guy was ill, went to the emergency room saying he was a danger to the world and they sent him honecwhere he cut the throat of his mother and was put in jail!.....So I a retired physician unable to program beyond rudimentary DOS commands, have the responsibility for maintaining a photography forum!

Comment: I would love to hear any suggestions as I have found acfellow who can program in PHP and it woukd be great to pass on, any routines for vacuuming up posted image URLs l, from various hosting sites), to get the images to populate a searchable database that I can use to host images free of charge and so protect folk from their favorite service simply going out of business or failing them in some way.